# How to query and get the distinct names from where someone walked in elasticsearch 7 with geoquery? Is it possible?

Tags: python, node.js, elasticsearch

Assuming I have data like this:

```
{
'name': 'George',
'wore': 'Slacks',
'time': 'time',
'location': {'lat': xxx, 'lon', xxx}
},
{
'name': 'George'
'wore': 'Slacks',
'time': 'time',
'location': {'lat': xxx, 'lon', xxx}
},
{
'name': 'William'
'time': 'time'
'wore': 'Jeans',
'location': {'lat': xxx, 'lon', xxx}
}
```

I can get a bounding box of all the points using the following elasticsearch search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_bounding_box" : {
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "top_left" : {
                            "lat" : 40.73,
                            "lon" : -74.1
                        },
                        "bottom_right" : {
                            "lat" : 40.01,
                            "lon" : -71.12
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

issue is, there are a lot of points where the 'name' is the same, but the location/lat/long and time are different. Does there exist a way where I can get a list of all the distinct names instead of getting results for all the individual points? Or at least a count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean. Maybe, you can use an aggregation terms query. It behaves just like 'group by' in sql.

GET /_search:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "a1" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "name" } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is the name field may appear 30 times, but reality of it is, it may be one person who generated the 30 points. Is there a way such that I only get the unique set of people or count of unique set of people?